# UIView switching transition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, core-animation

I want to make a splash screen that shows an UIImage view and a UIActivityIndictor then after the application has finished loading, it fades into a new view, I have no idea how to make one view "fade" (as in dissolve) into another view and I'm not sure how to "pause" the code until it finishes loading the background parts, any help?
Thanks so much!

Comment: There are quite a few apps in the store using the technique, Dropbox on iPad and iPhone are two popular apps using animated transitions from the splash screen, do you mean something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the below code shows a splash screen for 1 second, then it animates dissolving of the screen.

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade Out" context:nil];

// wait for time before begin, your splash screen shows for 1 second
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];

// duration of animation, the splash screen dissolved in quarter of a second.
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
viewToDissolve.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];

//animation complete, now show the main screen. you can use uinavigationviewcontroller or other methods.
```

Comment: is it advisable to use animation for splash screen?

Comment: well if you want to fad-out something you got to animate it right? personally I am against splash screens especially for touch devices. The app should be snappy & should immediately start showing stuff...

Comment: At the [self.view addSubview : view]; I have to add a name for the view for it to add, so I made an IBOutlet like so: (on the first view controller's .h file)

IBOutlet UIView *main;
But when I try to connect the *main; UIView to the view on the storyboard, it wont let me... Again, I'm sorry that I'm so stupid but I'm just trying to learn...

Comment: first off did the animation work? next, what you said is not clear. can you post some code or screenshots?

Comment: @JonSullivan dude, adding splash screen is not at all a good practice, and you are even adding more delay by giving animation, better try some  alternatives...my suggestion

Comment: Yeah it did, I need to know how to show a new view now..is it just [self.view addSubview : view]; ? and what do I put in place of 'view'?

Comment: yes `[self.view addSubview:yourmainView];` should work. also make sure you link `yourmainView` to the `UIView` if you are using Interface Builder.

Comment: Note that the beginAnimmations:context ... commitAnimations style of view animations is strongly discouraged under iOS 5. Much better to use the new animateWithDuration:animations: block-based animation methods. They are cleaner and easier to use, and are supported back to iOS 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties, select targets and Drag and drop your image to the Launch image section.

Comment: this wont give fade out effect